# bind, call and apply called directly on function signature

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been programming in JS for about a year, and I swear there was a way to do this:

```
function a(){

}.bind(this);
```

or

```
function a(){

}.apply(this,null);
```

I can do this:

```
(function a(){
    console.log('b');
}).apply(null);

a(); //but this will throw an error
```

is there a way to do what I am trying to do? I just want to invoke apply, call or bind on a function without losing scope.

Comment: Since the introduction of the language it has not been possible to use a function defined in a function declaration statement immediately in the same statement. Other than that, it's not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "losing scope"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
var a = function a() {
  // ...
}.bind(this);
```

? You can't use a function as an expression in the context of a function declaration statement; the syntax just doesn't allow it. However, you can get an effect very similar to a function declaration statement by instantiating the function in an expression and assigning the reference to a local variable, as above. When you do that, your function is instantiated in the context of an expression, and so using it as an object base to call `.bind()` works fine.

Comment: yes this is probably it

Comment: it should also work in an object literal, can you provide that syntax also as an example? {a: function(){}.bind(this)}

Comment: @AlexMills it's pretty much the same in an object literal - so long as the `function` keyword isn't the very first token in a *statement*, you're dealing with a function instantiation expression, and you can do the `.bind()` thing or anything else like that. Note that the right-hand side of a property declaration in an object initializer (`foo: function blah() ...`) is not a *statement* - it's part of the object initializer syntax, so the function part is just an expression, not a function declaration statement.

Comment: @Pointy To be pedantic, I don't recall hearing the expression "instantiate a function" or "instantiate a function in an expression". I thought it was just "function expression".

Comment: @torazaburo I am not a good source for accurate terminology. I personally like "function instantiation expression" because I think it captures what's going on, but I think you're right that the spec just calls it a "function expression".